# Expand container width beyond fit-content

Tags: html, css

This is my Table cell. It is as wide as the content it contains:

```
<td class="sticky calltd employeetd" style="width: fit-content;">
    Wintheiser Granville
</td>
```

Is there a way to set the width of the inner-part of my container 10px longer than "fit-content" like:

```
width: calc(fit-content + 10px); <---- doesn't work
```

I didn't find an equal question, but if there is one, please link it here.

---

Width:fit-content;

[image]

What i need:

[image]

**The blue Area needs to be a content space no  margin or  padding**

Comment: Try adding `padding-right: 10px`? That would work if you don't want text in the area.

Comment: Thats not a solution for my problem, i have text inside my cell and padding doesnt add content space

Comment: I don't think you can do this without js. I'll try something out.

Comment: Maybe you can try using ::after and setting it to `content: " "` and `width: 10px`? I'm not sure if that would work but you can give it a try. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159552/10464375

Comment: Wait that won't help you because you can't add text in it.

Comment: does **this** work : `width: calc(fit-content() + 10px)`

Comment: @St3an Unfortunately not

Comment: Could you add an image of the expected result?

Comment: Actually never used it, but it seems to apply on grid layout, as per [documentation for this function on MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content()). Could you provide us with more code, or create snippet ?

Comment: You may not use tables for layout.

Comment: and why it should not be a padding? in all the cases it's an extra width so padding will do the job perfectly

Comment: because i have a :hover effect on it, which size the text up. and you know the padding is no content space

Comment: @Elias such information should belong to the question and using padding won't prevent your hover effect. Better make your question complete and clear of what you want achieve if you want to get accurate answers, don't give use only 10% of the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes i know but the content space fits the conent that means if :hover and the content size up, the content is longer and DOESNT FITS THE CONTENT ANYMORE

Comment: don't tell this to me, make your question more clear. We should not have a discussion to explain to *me* what you want. Edit your question to include all the information so everyone get a clear non-ambiguous idea of what you want otherwise no one can answer your question

Comment: This information isnt important to answer this question, my question was just "is it possible to do this with CSS " if not my question is answered, if it is possible and how my question is answered too" if i add this information, user just think they must give me other solutions about my approach which i dont want/need

Comment: I have a ton of answers (and there is a ton of answers) but I won't waste my time to provide one and then you will later tell me "no, this one is not good because in the future I will be doing X and it won't be good" .. good luck getting your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not win any beauty contests, but here is a solution that at least gets you where I understand you want to go:

```
<td class="sticky calltd employeetd" style="width: fit-content;">
    Sheldon Cooper
    <div style="width: 10px; height: 0px; display: inline-block;"></div>
</td>
```

That way you just add a `div` container with zero height (meaning it is invisible) and your preferred width next to the content of your `td`.

In case your `fit-content` property is calculated based on the length of the `td`'s content, this will expand your width for `10px`. In case your `fit-content` is calculated based on something else, this doesn't help you.

Answer (score -5):

A small research led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680785/getting-width-of-a-div-element)

Gordon's answer mentions the following:

> CSS isn't a 'programming language'. You can't really make decisions, gather data, or manipulate anything the language wasn't designed to do. If you want to do that, javascript is your best choice

I'd also suggest JS for this, but im sure you thought of it.

In addition, notice the following:

> If you're comfortable with jQuery, you can just use $("#postanad").width().

Comment: You’ll be sorely mistaken to think CSS is not a programming language at all.

Comment: It was taken from another question's answer, as mentioned.